# Oblique full width layout with two columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

I need to create something like this, but I can't find any useful approach to create what I need.

Currently I'm using bootstrap v4.1 but any not-bootstrap solution is more than welcome!

Does someone have some resources / pen to share?

Thanks in advance

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt4jO.jpg)

Comment: read about skew() transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to provide too simple of an answer, because I'm not sure what you're going for exactly. Maybe try https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

I would look up transform layouts on codepen.

Here is one to codepen: /tommygeorge/pen/JaGaZj

Comment: Thank you! I used transform: matrix(1, -0.1, 0, 1, 0, 0); and now fits perfectly